# Why do unicode quotes appear around a regex capture in perl6?

Tags: regex, raku

I'm using rakudo, and the following code:

```
"foo" ~~ m/(foo)/;
say $0;
```

I thought the output would be:

```
foo
```

However, I get:

```
｢foo｣
```

(That's foo with some weird unicode-y quote marks around it.)

I cannot find anything about this in the documentation, and I can't seem to get rid of those quotes. What's happening here?

Edit: Doing

```
say "$0";
```

instead gets rid of the quote marks, and both of

```
print $0;
print "$0";
```

do too. So I guess the capture isn't actually a string, and putting double quotes around it somehow turns it into a string? (By the way, $0.gist produces ｢foo｣, not foo.) Can anyone point me to the part of the documentation where I can learn about this behavior? I'm coming from Perl, and thoroughly confused.

Comment: https://docs.perl6.org/language/quoting#The_Q_Lang

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `say` sub calls the `.gist` method. By contrast, the `print` sub calls the `.Str` method. There's also a `put` sub ("print using terminator"), which calls `.Str` and then does a newline. That's probably what you want to be using instead of `say`.

The `.gist` and `.Str` methods are two different ways to turn an object into a `Str`. The `.gist` method provides a human-friendly representation of the data that conveys its structure. If you `.gist` a complex `Match` whith a bunch of captures, it will show those (and use indentation to display the match tree). By contrast, `.Str` doesn't try to reproduce structure; on a `Match` object, it just gives the text that the `Match` covers.

So, to summarize the differences between the Perl 5 and Perl 6 languages that you're running into:

- Captures are `Match` objects, not strings (which is why grammars can produce a parse tree)
- The `say` function in Perl 6 calls `.gist`
- The `put` function in Perl 6 is mostly equivalent to the `say` function in Perl 5

Finally, the square quotes were picked because they are relatively rare, and thus unlikely to be in any user data, and therefore allow a presentation of the captured data that is very unlikely to need any escape sequences in it. That provides a more easily readable overview of the `Match` in question, which is the aim of `.gist`.

Answer (score 1):

A [capture](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#Capturing) returns a [Match](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Match) which stringifies to the matched string as you discovered.

[Grouping and Capturing](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#Grouping_and_Capturing) says

> An unquantified capture produces a Match object.

BTW, You can see what type the variable actually holds with `.WHAT`:

```
say $0.WHAT;
(Match)
```

Comment: If you are just printing out the name of the type use `.^name` not `.WHAT`.